# undefined $username using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, undefined

I am programming in PHP.

I want to do a page that if the user didn't signed in, the system will say "Hello Guest" and if he signed in, the system will say "Hello $username".

It's working, however, when I entered the system for the first time I receive a error undefined $Username. After I refresh the page or going to another page it's working good - the problem is in the first time.

The $username received in the login page and there is `session_start();`.

This code is from the page I am trying to do the Hello Username:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    if ($_SESSION["Username"] == "")
        $_SESSION["Username"] = "Guest";    
?>
```

Need help

Comment: the code you posted doesn't support the question/error. `undefined $Username` unless you meant (minus the $ sign) `undefined Username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `isset()`

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["Username"]))
    $_SESSION["Username"] = "Guest";    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have used $username you have to check if it exist using

```
if(isset($username)){

}
```

If not then you have to set it.